# Condition to ensure that this producer-consumer example won't deadlock?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, semaphore

I started to doubt about the concept of semaphores; please read well to understand my problem...

According to the manual, `sem_post` will unlock a thread when the semaphore's value becomes greater than `0`... so if I have this code:

```
void* producer(void* arg)
{
    while(1)
    {
        sem_wait(&sem_produce);
        sem_wait(&mutex);
        // Insert item into buffer
        sem_post(&mutex);
        sem_post(&sem_consume);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void* consumer(void* arg)
{
    while(1)
    {
        sem_wait(&sem_consume);
        sem_wait(&mutex);
        // Remove item from buffer
        sem_post(&mutex);
        sem_post(&sem_produce);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Where `sem_consume` is initialized with the value of `0`, and `sem_produce` is initialized with `N`.

What happens if, for example, the `N` consumers run before producers and try to consume? Then `sem_consume` should have the value of `-N`, and if then there are `N` insertions, `sem_consume` and `sem_produce` both should be `0`, or am I wrong? Then that means the consumers would be stuck because (according to the manual) `sem_post` will unlock a thread when the semaphore's value becomes greater than zero...

So from what I understand from the manual and considering the above example, the only way this program would work fine is if `sem_consume` never reach the value of `-N`.

I am right? If yes, how can I improve the example so it won't get stuck? If the answer is no, in what I was wrong?

Comment: "then sem_consume should have the value of -N". That can never happen. It's written all over the semaphore manuals. [sem_overview manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html) says: "A semaphore is an integer whose value is **never allowed to fall below zero**". [sem_wait](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_wait.3.html): "If the semaphore currently has the value zero, then the call blocks until either it becomes possible to perform the decrement (i.e., the semaphore value rises above zero), or a signal handler interrupts the call.".

Comment: If the consumers run before the producers, then the consumers will all wait on `sem_consume` until a producer has managed to do `sem_post(&sem_consume)`, won't they?  And only one consumer will get to run for each `sem_post(&sem_consume)`.  There'll be `N` items queued before the producers get blocked waiting for a consumer to consume.

Comment: That's odd , in my parallel programming course I thought I heard from the teacher that the value of a semaphore could be negative and that this negative value would represent the number of blocked threads, if this value can't be negative then I have no doubts.

Comment: "the value of a semaphore could be negative and that this negative value would represent the number of blocked threads" You can certainly view it this way. This doesn't really contradict what @kaylum says. A program can never see a negative semaphore value, because when the value is negative, a program that attempts to grab it blocks. With that, you never *initialize* a semaphore with a negative value. Only a thread that attempts to grab a semaphore can result in its dropping below zero.

Answer (score 0):

> So from what I understand from the manual and considering the above
>   example, the only way this program would work fine is if sem_consume
>   never reach the value of -N.

Thats correct, semaphores are just flat out not permitted to be a negative value period. As pointed out by many people in the comments, the semaphore manuals clearly state this:

> [A semaphore is an integer whose value is never allowed to fall below
>          zero.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html)

And this:

> [If the semaphore
>          currently has the value zero, then the call blocks until either it
>          becomes possible to perform the decrement (i.e., the semaphore value
>          rises above zero), or a signal handler interrupts the call.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_wait.3.html)

And this:

> [Decrementing is a (possibly) blocking function. If the resulting semaphore value is negative, the calling thread or process is blocked, and cannot continue until some other thread or process increments it.](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~rich/class/cs170/notes/Semaphores/)

Essentially, the entire point of a semaphore being positive only is that when a process tries to decrement it into a negative, that process gets halted until another process increments it sufficiently for it not to become negative when the original process is allowed to decrement.

To your comment:

> That's odd , in my parallel programming course I thought I heard from the teacher that the value of a semaphore could be negative and that this negative value would represent the number of blocked threads, if this value can't be negative then I have no doubts.

Thats essentially what happens, but you can't view this value. If you attempt to grab a semaphore which is currently not positive, then the function trying to grab it is blocked until it becomes positive again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the definitions of sem_post and sem_wait are as follows.

sem_wait()
    Decrements the value of semaphore by one and wait if the value is negative.

sem_post()
    Increments the value of semaphore by one and if there are one or more threads waiting then wake one.

Hence sem_post() does not really check if the value is greater than 0 or not.

Also, if sem_post() really checks that then semaphore can never be used as a lock. Please see the below code snippet.

```
sem_t m;
sem_init(&m, 0, 1)

sem_wait(&m)
... critical section...
sem_post(&m)
```

Let's say, thread 1 gets scheduled first and decrements the value to 0 and enters the critical section. Before it completes, three other threads get scheduled one after another and each of them further decrements the semaphore and blocks. Now, thread 1 gets scheduled again, completes the critical section and calls sem_post(). My point is that if it really checks for a positive value then other threads will never be scheduled which is not the case. Please let me know if this answers your question.

Thank you.